# two div left right with auto width

Tags: css, html

```
<div id="leftdiv" style="background: yellow; min-width: 400px; max-width: 800px;">left content left content left content</div>

<div id="rightdiv" style="background: red; width: 250px;">right content right content right content</div>
```

I put the `float: left` in the left div max-width and min-width not working.
How can i fix this ?

Comment: give float left to both divs

Comment: what do you really want?

Answer (score 4):

Float right div must be before left coz it gives trouble in some version of ie

```
<div id="rightdiv" >right content right content right content</div>
<div id="leftdiv">left content left content left content</div>
```

CSS same as bot

```
#leftdiv
{
    background-color:Yellow;
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:800px;
    float:left;
}

#rightdiv
{
    background-color:red;
    width:250px;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Move your `right` div before the `left` one:

```
<div id="rightdiv" >right content right content right content</div>
<div id="leftdiv">left content left content left content</div>
```

And now **just** `float` the `right` one:

```
#leftdiv {
    background: yellow;
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 800px;
}

#rightdiv {
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}
```

Check this [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/Xdmqk/) to see is that you want or not.

- `[!]` I've reduce `width` of `right` element to see the result in my monitor. You can use the old one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want one of 2 divs to shrink when the viewport is resized, it is wisest to either do as Andi Muqisth said, and use percentages to resize yourd divs, or make one the parent of the other, like so:
Demo: http://jsbin.com/ileyaf/4/edit

```
<div id="leftdiv">left content left content left content
    <div id="rightdiv">right content right content right content</div>
</div>
```

```
#leftdiv  {
    background: yellow; 
    width: 100%;
 }
#rightdiv {
    background: red; 
    max-width: 250px;
    float: right;
 }
```

Comment: You can't see ? left div is should be max width and will be dynamic.

Comment: for id use # in css to apply styles . for class in css

Answer (score 0):

Float left seems working.. see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y77g/10/)

```
<div id="leftdiv">left content left content left content</div>
<div id="rightdiv" >right content right content right content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#leftdiv
{
    background-color:Yellow;
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:800px;
    float:left;
}

#rightdiv
{
    background-color:red;
    width:250px;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Left div is not dynamic width,

Comment: make the min-width:auto to make it dynamic. see the updated fiddle

Comment: Left div is should be dynamic and right div is should be fixed 250px

Comment: Left div is should be max width of the container div

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I solved the problem.

Here is the example:

   

    #container { position: relative; }
    #left { margin-right: 270px; /* 250px right div width and 20px space */ }
    #right { position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; width: 250px; }


Thanks everybody

Comment: sorry i really dont understand your question. Do you want that the width of #leftdiv is equal to 800px?

Comment: ah. ok glad you make it. :) just answer your own question below.

Answer (score 0):

if you specify left side div first   then simply put

```
<div style="float:left">
</div> 
<div style="clear:both">
</div> 
<div style="float:right">
</div>
```

else if you specify right side div first there is no need of clear both

```
<div style="float:right">
</div>
<div style="float:left">
</div>
```